# Mixing Plural AND Singular naming

Tags: naming-conventions, singular

here's the quick version of the situation:

We are developing some C# App and the team decided this Naming convention:

We have for example an entity called User which is stored in the DB, we have the old master/slave pages to manage the User catallog. We are using a sort of MVC pattern, so for the master we have this controller called **UsersController** and the controller for the slave is **UserController**. We have invested all the time that we are willing to invest in this discution (5 mins).

I think that this naming convention is error prone or at least confusing. What would be your position on this (just naming, not about the SORT of MVC pattern)? suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It took me about 3 reads before I noticed that there was an "s" is one of them... so I would say it is a little error prone. I would probably rename it to UserCollectionController if it were my code.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to skim a lot of code - answering questions, etc. The difference between *user* and *users* is a little too subtle. They don't stand apart visually.